# Wrong timestamp from std::chrono when using static date

Tags: c++, time, c++20

I feed a static date into std::chrono and expect the following timestamp `1703064951` (today at 10:35:51 in Germany).

[image]

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::chrono::system_clock::time_point a;
    a = std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, std::chrono::seconds>(std::chrono::seconds(51));
    a += std::chrono::minutes(35);
    a += std::chrono::hours(10);
    a += std::chrono::days(20);
    a += std::chrono::months(12);
    a += std::chrono::years(53);

    std::cout << "New: " << std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(a) << '\n';
}
```

But I get the result

```
New: 1705841559
```

What is the reason for it?

Comment: Oh, you only meant to add 11 months (December - January)?  And only 9 hours (since epoch is specified as 00:00 UTC)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `std::chrono::duration` of "1 month" or "1 year" is a fixed-length *nominal* month, rather than an exact number of days.  We can see this by printing the intermediate values:

```
{
    auto a = std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, std::chrono::seconds>(std::chrono::seconds(51));
    a += std::chrono::minutes(35);
    a += std::chrono::hours(10);
    a += std::chrono::days(20);
    std::cout << "New: " << a << " = " << std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(a) << '\n';

    a += std::chrono::months(12);
    std::cout << "New: " << a << " = " << std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(a) << '\n';

    a += std::chrono::years(53);
    std::cout << "New: " << a << " = " << std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(a) << '\n';
```

We see:

```
New: 1970-01-21 10:35:51 = 1766151
New: 1971-01-21 16:25:03 = 33323103
New: 2024-01-21 12:52:39 = 1705841559
```

The C++17 `<chrono>` library doesn't do calendrical calculations such as you seem to be expecting.  For that, you'll want the newer (C++20) types such as `std::chrono::year_month_day`.

Answer (score 2):

`std::chrono::system_clock` almost certainly works with UTC, so you should try the translation according to UTC.

Furthermore, even if you're looking at 2023-12-20 09:35:51 UTC, doing the calculation like what you did won't work. The reason is you're adding the durations up assuming it will give you the corresponding date, but it doesn't work like that. Have a look at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration, you'll see that `minutes`, `hours`, `days`, `months`, and `years` are just different ways to write seconds, and adding these up won't give you the date you want (leap years and stuff).

To do what you want, try something like

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    using namespace std::chrono;

    system_clock::time_point a = sys_days{year{2023}/December/day{20}}
        + hours{9} + minutes{35} + seconds{51};

    std::cout << "New: " << system_clock::to_time_t(a) << '\n';
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/nqz8oxnoP

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that increments don't set the "fields" of the timestamp – they just add that duration to it.

So, for instance, `a += std::chrono::months(12);` is equivalent to `a += std::chrono::years(1);`, and `a += std::chrono::years(53);` is equivalent to `a += std::chrono::months(53 * 12);`

The "faulty" timestamp has the date 2024-01-21, and it is because:

The calendar starts at 1970-01-01.
Add 20 days: 1970-01-21.
Add 12 months: 1971-01-21.
Add 53 years: 2024-01-21.